# Kotlin Reflection with Proguard fails

Tags: java, kotlin, proguard, kotlin-reflect

Let's say I have this class

```
data class Person(val name: String?)
```

When I proguard and run the app I am getting the following exception

```
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: No accessors or field is found for property val com.whatever.packagee.Person.name: kotlin.String?
```

I also found that the issue is thrown from this [reflection](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/KPropertyImpl.kt#L239) codebase. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please show how exactly you're using reflection in your code.

Comment: I'm actually using Moshi to serialise the JSON.

Comment: Annotate the class with @Keep to prevent it from being altered by proguard.

Comment: @RobCo I have already added it in proguard rules. -keep, -keepclassmembers for the whole package with wildcard.

Comment: maybe see https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/315

Comment: Did you eventually figured this one out? I'm getting this error with Jackson

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure to not use too broad -keep options, this will prevent ProGuard from properly optimising and shrinking the code.

It's important to preserve the fields of classes you wish to serialise. Based on the exception you see I would expect a -keep option similar to the one below would do the trick;

```
-keep class com.whatever.packagee.Person {
    <fields>;
}
```

You can experiment with these -keep options via the ProGuard Playground, which is quite useful to see what parts of code are affected with your -keep rules. This way you can inspect if all cases of serialization were tackled. I created a Playground for this particular case: [Playground link](https://playground.proguard.com/p/Kg9wNM)

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me.

Add following to proguard rules

-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**

-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }